# Law of doubles - some things don't work right on the site

Tags: bug

I noticed 3, but at time of writing I can only remember 2:

1. If you are in the editor and writing a question or answer, and "undo" (CTRL-Z), it undoes 2 steps. If you then redo, it only goes forward one of those undoings (but sometimes both, it's weird). I've not seen this in other SA's
2. This is new in the last month or less: opening the inbox dropdown and clicking on an unread item, which takes you to the comment or answer etc. that it is talking about, doesn't mark the item as unread anymore (at least most of the time). Doing it twice does seem to do so.

Is this issue my end or are others noticing this? Is this the correct place to raise it to staff?

EDIT: I think 3) is the issue on mobile, when editing an answer, and then hitting Save Changes, it just scrolls to the top of the answer for absolutely no reason, and you have to scroll down again and hit it a second time for it to save changes.

Comment: I also experience issues with your second one. You'll need to click "Mark all as read" - that does the trick, but it shouldn't be that difficult indeed.